# Can my H1B visa be transferred to another company, and before Oct 1st 2017?

Tags: working-visas, immigration, h1-visa

Company A has applied for my H1B and it was approved. Now, I have another opportunity from Company B and it is ready to sponsor my H1B visa. Can I transfer my H1B to Company B before Oct 1st 2017 (without any paystubs from Company A, a I never worked for it before)?

I'm currently in the US on an F1 student visa.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [H1B Transfer Before Oct 1st](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/8339/h1b-transfer-before-oct-1st), as well as [this on the misnomer 'transfer'](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/11073/i-have-an-approved-h1b-petition-but-my-employer-has-stopped-hiring-can-i-get-i/11699#11699)